# Что за слайдер в PSD макете?

Tags: вёрстка, веб-дизайн, слайдер

Не могу найти готовое решение для слайдера на скриншоте (скриншот PSD макета). Не обязательно точно такой же слайдер достаточно похожего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На фото изображены табы, а не слайдер. [Вот пример на чистом CSS](https://itchief.ru/examples/lab.php?topic=css&file=tabs-v4). [Ещё один пример](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-build-a-responsive-tab-component-with-css-and-a-touch-of-javascript--cms-30456) уже с js.
Выглядят он не как ваши, но считайте, что активное видео - это контент, а превью к видео - вкладки.